# Is there an order of adjectives in Japanese?

Tags: adjectives, i-adjectives, na-adjectives, word-order

In English, if we have multiple adjectives modifying a noun, there is a preferred order for those adjectives, for example:

> nice long red car
>
> *nice red long car
>
> *long red nice car

I was wondering if there are similar restrictions in Japanese. For example, take the following three sentences.

> おもしろくてハンサムで親切な人
>
> ハンサムで親切でおもしろい人
>
> 親切でおもしろくてハンサムな人

Do any of these sound strange, or unnatural? Or are they incorrect? Or do no such restrictions exist in Japanese?

Comment: I wondered about this as well. I asked a Japanese person about this.
I said おいしくて　しっぱくて　あついラーメン, which he corrected as
あつくて　しょっぱくて　おいしいラーメン. He couldn't explain why, he just thought that adjectives that show opinions, like おいしい or おもしろい, feel better when they're last.  
I'm looking for grammar sources to explain this. If anyone has any grammar book recommendations, please let me know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Tim Sensei](http://ww8.tiki.ne.jp/~tmath/language/adjectives.htm#04):

> In Japanese there is no "proper order" for adjectives. When the adjectives come before the noun they describe, you start with the one you want to emphasize most.

Answer (score 1):

> おもしろくてハンサムで親切な人
>
> ハンサムで親切でおもしろい人
>
> 親切でおもしろくてハンサムな人

I think all the three are perfectly fine. You can say whichever you like.